# Micronaut Configure micronaut-jdbc-tomcat Data source for MySQL

Tags: micronaut

In Development I am using below configuration to connect to MySQL database. I like to use Tomcat  Data source for MySql Connection. Didn’t find example in the Micronaut document page.

What change required in application.yaml file to use Tomcat Datasource?

```
---
datasources.default: {}
---
hibernate:
  hbm2ddl:
    auto: update
  cache:
    queries: false
    use_second_level_cache: true
    use_query_cache: false
    region.factory_class: org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory
dataSource:
  url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db
  dbCreate: create-update
  pooled: true
  jmxExport: true
  driverClassName: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
  dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
  username:  
  password:
```

Comment: Hikari (which is way better than Tomcat) is supported out-of-the-box, with almost no effort; you would only need to import `io.micronaut.configuration:micronaut-jdbc-hikari` and do pretty much what you are doing here. If you are willing to change it I can send you the complete config as an answer.

Comment: @x80486 I used Tomcat and Grails befoe thought of using  the same datasource for Micronaut also. please post Hikari configuration I will test it.

Answer (score 2):

While configuring your data source in JPA, you can take advantage of Hikari; first you would need to import these:

```
implementation "io.micronaut.configuration:micronaut-hibernate-jpa"
implementation "io.micronaut.configuration:micronaut-jdbc-hikari"
```

I'm assuming you already have `micronaut-hibernate-jpa`, but I put it anyway. Additionally you can also add `H2` as `runtimeOnly` (like `runtimeOnly "com.h2database:h2"`) so it's easier to bootstrap and test the application.

After that, all you would need is to add these in your `application.yml`:

```
datasources:
  default:
    driverClassName: ${JDBC_DRIVER:org.h2.Driver}
    password: ${JDBC_PASSWORD:""}
    url: ${JDBC_URL:`jdbc:h2:mem:test_db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;MODE=PostgreSQL`}
    username: ${JDBC_USER:sa}
```

...and you should be all set! An *almost fully* working example is [here](https://github.com/x80486/kotlin-micronaut/).

> `datasources` is located at the root in `application.yml`, not as a child of any other key(s).

Last but not least, if you need to add more settings to tweak the data source configuration a little bit, you can reference [these](https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/configurationreference.html#io.micronaut.configuration.jdbc.hikari.DatasourceConfiguration) settings.

Comment: I am using `micronaut-hibernate-gorm` with GROM dataservice.  from the `application.yaml` file where are you referencing Hikari class. trying to understand how Micronaut detect Data source class. Thanks for the post.

Comment: Also is it possible to read the database connection from file instanced of setting the environment variable?

Comment: @sfgroups, if you want to pass `datasources.default.url` as an environment variable you can use `JDBC_URL` for that – I typically used that approach in/with my `docker-compose.yml` file(s); if nothing is provided, the default will be used – a "little bit risky" for delivering something like that to higher environments, but perfectly fine for prototyping.

Comment: I want to read the connection from kubernetes configmap and secret map. thats why I am looking for the option to read from the file.

Answer (score 1):

you need mysql connector.

I am using this version.

```
compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version:'5.1.47'
```

[see this site.](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java) If you are using Mysql 5.x you need 5.x's Drivers and using `driverClassName: "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"`. But if you are using Mysql 8.x , you need 8.x's Driver and using `driverClassName: "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"`

it depends on your Mysql version.

and you need one of this:

```
compile "io.micronaut.configuration:micronaut-hibernate-jpa"
compile "io.micronaut.configuration:micronaut-jdbc-hikari"
```

or you can use

```
compile "io.micronaut.configuration:micronaut-jdbc-tomcat"
compile "io.micronaut.configuration:micronaut-hibernate-jpa"
```

see this guide :

> http://guides.micronaut.io/micronaut-data-access-jpa-hibernate/guide/index.html

Comment: we are including this entry in the build.gradle file. May I know how micronaut  know which JDBC driver to use? what happens if we include both hikari and jdbc-tomcat entry in `build.gradle` file?